# Imperfecto - comía vs estaba comiendo?

Tags: gramática

Todavía estoy estudiando. Gracias por su paciencia.

Dos formas de decir:

> Yo no soy médico, pero creo que ella comía por dos.
>
> Yo no soy médico, pero creo que ella estaba comiendo por dos.

¿Cuál es más común?

¿Ambos son correctos?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ambos son correctos, pero pueden tener un significado ligeramente distinto. "Ella comía mucho" puede expresar que es algo que ocurría en general en el pasado. "Ella estaba comiendo mucho" expresa que eso ocurría en un momento particular. De todas formas, depende del contexto y pueden intercambiarse estos usos. Ejemplo de esto: "ella comía por dos mientras la miraba", "ella estaba comiendo por dos en aquella época".

A la hora de usar "estar" en imperfecto + gerundio (ella estaba comiendo), hay que tener en cuenta que es incorrecto si se indica la duración: "ella estaba comiendo dos horas" es incorrecto, lo correcto es "ella estuvo comiendo dos horas".